# Inconsistent results when using the tabout command

Tags: stata

I want to use the *community-contributed* command `tabout` to produce a summary table.

However, the output is inconsistent in a simple cross tab.

The code below is a limited sample of what I am trying to do:

```
tab demaut revyn if demaut<.5

           |   Revolution (Y/N)
    Polity |        NO        YES |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         0 |       341         13 |       354 
       .05 |       682         91 |       773 
        .1 |       309         55 |       364 
       .15 |     1,171        259 |     1,430 
        .2 |       409         96 |       505 
       .25 |       149         80 |       229 
        .3 |       191         32 |       223 
       .35 |       268         82 |       350 
        .4 |       172         23 |       195 
       .45 |       165         75 |       240 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |     3,857        806 |     4,663 

The total observations are 4,663.
```

However, if I use:

```
tabout demaut using temp.tex if demaut<.5, replace c(N revyn mean revyn) sum one
```

Table output written to: `temp.tex`

```
Polity  N       Mean
        revyn   revyn
0       354.0   0.0
.05     0.0     
.1      0.0     
.15     0.0     
.2      0.0     
.25     229.0   0.3
.3      0.0     
.35     350.0   0.2
.4      195.0   0.1
.45     0.0     
Total   4,663.0 0.2
```

All the observations for `demaut = .05,.1,.15...` are missing and yet the total observations is correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear

tab mpg foreign if mpg < 20

   Mileage |       Car type
     (mpg) |  Domestic    Foreign |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
        12 |         2          0 |         2 
        14 |         5          1 |         6 
        15 |         2          0 |         2 
        16 |         4          0 |         4 
        17 |         2          2 |         4 
        18 |         7          2 |         9 
        19 |         8          0 |         8 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |        30          5 |        35 


tabout mpg foreign using temp.tex if mpg < 20, replace c(count mpg) format(0c) sum

Table output written to: temp.tex

        Car type                
Mileage (mpg)   Domestic        Foreign Total
        Count mpg       Count mpg       Count mpg
12      2       0       2
14      5       1       6
15      2       0       2
16      4       0       4
17      2       2       4
18      7       2       9
19      8       0       8
Total   30      5       35
```

Also:

```
tabout mpg foreign using temp.tex if mpg < 20, replace c(N mpg mean mpg) sum one

Table output written to: temp.tex

        N       Mean
        mpg     mpg
Mileage (mpg)           
12      2.0     12.0
14      6.0     14.0
15      2.0     15.0
16      4.0     16.0
17      4.0     17.0
18      9.0     18.0
19      8.0     19.0
Total   35.0    16.7

Car type                
Domestic        30.0    16.7
Foreign 5.0     16.8
Total   35.0    16.7
```